# Has the word lust got any positive meaning to it?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, synonyms

I've been hearing it quite a while... Sexual desire is the only meaning I know... But have heard people using it positively too.. Which doesn't seem to be giving that "sexual desire" sort of relation to it.

Comment: Lust:  *Intense eagerness or enthusiasm: a lust for life.* http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lust

Comment: I am confused by what you mean when you say "I have heard people using it positively too", there is nothing inherently negative or wrong with the definition you knew about.

Comment: I have no closevotes left today. But this is completely a matter of opinion (and context).

Comment: I don't see anything negative about sexual desire, but the word is commonly used in other contexts, almost always positively.

Comment: @Yeshe for example... "a dad's lust is only for his 10yr old son for whom he comes back once in every month"

Comment: @SandeepMishra, I can say, "Some people **love** to violently rape and murder people."  but reflects nothing about the nature of love.
Any word can be used in a sentence negatively, that does not make the word inherently negative.

Comment: Even in a positive context, *lust* implies such an exaggerated, almost out of control feeling that most of the positive effect is lost.  If you apply it to someone else usually the response would be to deny the feeling is so strong.

Comment: @Oldcat Not necessarily. If you say someone has lust for life, that just means he's exuberant.

Comment: There is a nice book on architectural features called 'A Lust For Windowsills', and I have voraciously, I would almost say lustily, read the book, but not once did I feel the urge to poke my little fellow into a 16th century letterbox, although some were described as being newly fitted with hairy draught excluders on the inside, to dry-hump a Victorian lamppost or to stick a cupola where the sun doesn't shine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think many uses of *lust* are positive, a number of examples were given in the comments.

The context where it generally has a negative connotation is when it's used to describe a purely sexual attraction to another person, usually without any notion of affection or even friendship. It's considered to be giving in to baser, animal instincts, rather than human emotions.

There are some other contexts where an extreme desire might cause someone to act negatively, and these could also be described as lust. For instance, lust for money might prompt a financial professional to swindle their clients.